# No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API runs a stored procedure and returns the records from the table.The record includes the int field called CounterSeq

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Get(string Account)
{
  // other code for connecting to the SQL seerver and calling the stored procedure
 reader = command.ExecuteReader(); 
 List<QueryResult>qresults = new List<QueryResult>();
  while (reader.Read())
 {  
   QueryResult qr = new QueryResult();
   qr.AccountID = reader["AccountID"].ToString();
   qr.CounterSeq = reader["CounterSeq"].ToString("000");
   qresults.Add(qr);
 }
 DbConnection.Close();
 return Ok(qresults);
```

To have the CounterSeq to have the response as "001","010","100". It thows the error like `No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments` in `reader["CounterSeq"].ToString("000");`

Comment: If `reader["CounterSeq"]` is an integer, then cast it to `int` first, then do your `ToString`

Comment: The error message is incredibly clear. There are no overloads for ToString that receive an argument. Not sure what part of that is confusing. Are you trying to format that string or something?

Comment: If the `CounterSeq` has to be formatted like you mention in your post, [`reader["CounterSeq"].ToString().PadLeft(3, '0')`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padleft(v=vs.110).aspx) should do

Comment: You can use `String.Format()`

Comment: Please re-read [MCVE] guidance and pay close attention to "minimal". To demonstrate this problem you need just one line (probably `((object)42).ToString("000")` - definitely no need for DB code at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`reader["CounterSeq"]` returns `object` so first you have to cast it to `int` and next invoke `ToString("000")` like as:

```
((int)reader["CounterSeq"]).ToString("000")
```